# How to solve the problem of type error in django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am trying to make newsletter working but whenever I enter an email it gives me the following error.

**Following error**

```
TypeError at /
NewsletterUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'newsletteremail'

newsletteruser = NewsletterUser(newsletteremail=newsletteremail)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newsletteremail = request.POST.get('newsletteremail', '')

        newsletteruser = NewsletterUser(newsletteremail=newsletteremail)

        newsletteruser.save()
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(NewsletterUser)
```

**models.py**

```
class NewsletterUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `newsletteruser = NewsletterUser(newsletteremail=newsletteremail)`, you are assigninig `request.POST.get('newsletteremail', '')` to the db column `newsletteremail` but there is no column with name `newsletteremail` in your `NewsletterUser` model. In your model the field name is `email`. So the correct way to assigning value will be `db_column = some_value`. In this case, it will be:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newsletteremail = request.POST.get('newsletteremail', '')

        newsletteruser = NewsletterUser(email=newsletteremail)

        newsletteruser.save()
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```